# How to match the coupled string with regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to match this kind of format:

> AA sysodufsoufdds AA

Where AA can be arbitary consecutive string with no space in it.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
   ^(\w+).*?\1$
```

This will match any char sequence followed by anything followed by same char seq at the front. So it'll match:

```
AA sysodufsoufdds AA
BBB sysodufsoufdds BBB
ABC sysodufsoufdds ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
AA.*?AA
```

or to match whole string

```
^AA.*?AA$
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches a chunk of characters followed by a space followed by anything followed a space followed by the first chunk of characters...

```
([A-Z0-9]+) .* \1
```

There are a number of different ways of matching these bits.  The key thing is the use of `\1`, which is a *backrefrence* to the first defined pattern.  If you had two patterns you could use `\2` to refer to the second one.  For instance this ...

```
([A-Z0-9]+) (.*) \1 \2
```

... would match this string

```
AA sysodufsoufdds AA sysodufsoufdds
```